# How to generate a new data frame by matching common values in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames like this:

```
data_2019_dict = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Texas', 'Pennsylvania', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'Nevada', 'Ohio', 'Virginia', 'Louisiana', 'Florida', 'Nevada'],
 'industry': ['Agriculture', 'Agriculture', 'Agriculture', 'Agriculture', 'Medicine', 'Medicine', 'Medicine', 'Medicine', 'Manufacture', 'Manufacture', 'Manufacture'],
 'value': [3.6, 3.2, 2.9, 2.4, 3.1, 1.5, 1.4, 0.9, 4.4, 2.0, 1.9]}

data_2020_dict = {'state': ['Kansas', 'Texas', 'California', 'Idaho', 'Nevada', 'Ohio', 'Virginia', 'Louisiana', 'Texas', 'Nevada'],
 'industry': ['Agriculture', 'Agriculture', 'Agriculture', 'Medicine', 'Medicine', 'Finance', 'Finance', 'Manufacture', 'Manufacture', 'Manufacture'],
'value': [2.3, 1.8, 1.6, 7.2, 5.9, 4.1, 0.2, 5.1, 2.3, 2.2]}

data_2019 = pd.DataFrame(data_2019_dict)
data_2020 = pd.DataFrame(data_2020_dict)
```

Each data frame shows that in a year, which states perform well in those industries. What I want to generate, but get stuck, is: For each state, what industries are performed well in both years? The resulting data frame will look like this:

[image]

```
# Manually generated for illustration 
data_both_dict = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Texas', 'Pennsylvania', 'Nevada', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'Virginia', 'Louisiana', 'Florida', 'Kansas', 'California', 'Idaho'],
             'common_industry': ['', 'Agriculture', '', 'Medicine', 'Manufacture', '', '', 'Manufacture', '', '', '', ''],
             'common_industry_count': [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
data_both = pd.DataFrame(data_both_dict)
```

Comment: Have you defined a threshold for what "performing well" means?

Comment: @DJK The values are hypothetical and the data are simplified to just highlight the technical issue that I need help. But it's true that the values may be confusing and they are not relevant to this specific problem/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for common rows by both columns, rename column and add counts by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = (data_2019.merge(data_2020, on=['state','industry'])
               .rename(columns={'industry':'common_industry'}))
df['common_industry_count'] = df['state'].map(df['state'].value_counts())
df = df[['state','common_industry','common_industry_count']]
print (df)
       state common_industry  common_industry_count
0      Texas     Agriculture                      1
1     Nevada        Medicine                      2
2  Louisiana     Manufacture                      1
3     Nevada     Manufacture                      2
```

Then get all states by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with removed duplicates by [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and one column DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
both = pd.concat([data_2019['state'], data_2020['state']]).drop_duplicates().to_frame()
print (both)
          state
0          Ohio
1         Texas
2  Pennsylvania
3        Nevada
4      New York
7      Virginia
8     Louisiana
9       Florida
0        Kansas
2    California
3         Idaho
```

Last merge with `left` join and replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = both.merge(df, how='left')
df['common_industry_count'] = df['common_industry_count'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df['common_industry'] = df['common_industry'].fillna('')
print (df)
           state common_industry  common_industry_count
0           Ohio                                      0
1          Texas     Agriculture                      1
2   Pennsylvania                                      0
3         Nevada        Medicine                      2
4         Nevada     Manufacture                      2
5       New York                                      0
6       Virginia                                      0
7      Louisiana     Manufacture                      1
8        Florida                                      0
9         Kansas                                      0
10    California                                      0
11         Idaho                                      0
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.